# Setting each lines from file to char*

Tags: c

I'm attempting to set each line of a file, into an `char *arr[]`.

For Example, I have an file set like this
arq.txt:

```
linha1
linha2
linha3
linha4
linha5
linha6
linha7
linha8
linha9
linha10
```

I want to store `linha1` into the first position from my string array, so `arr[0] = "linha1"`
What I have coded to attempt to obtain this result was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *in_file  = fopen("arq.txt", "r"); 
    char singleLine[150];
    char* test[30];
    int i = 0;

    if (!in_file) 
    {   
        printf("Error! Could not open file\n"); 
        return 0;
    }

    while (!feof(in_file)){
        fgets(singleLine, 150, in_file);
        if (i == 0){
            test[0] = singleLine;
            puts(singleLine);
        }
        i++;
    }

    size_t length = sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);
    printf("Size: %d", length);

    printf("Here: %s\n", test[0]);

    fclose(in_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Althought, the result from that is printing the wrong data value:

```
(puts): linha1
Size: 30
Here: linha10
```

I attempted to get the size of the array from the content inside of it, so in this case, having only one element, I should have gotten 1 instead of 30.

Comment: Removing the C++ tag since you're clearly not using any C++ features. Otherwise I would suggest a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read text from file into Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581993/how-to-read-text-from-file-into-array)

Comment: size_t length = sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);
 printf("Size: %d", length); - this code will always give you 30 as you are statically assigning  memory

Comment: 1/ [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/3545273) and 2/ `test` is an array of pointers which will all point to the real same string `singleLine`. You should use `strdup` to allocate a new copy for each line (and free them when done...)

Comment: Nilton Schumacher F, who or what text suggested `while (!feof(in_file)){...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `test[0]` is a pointer, which points to the initial element of the array `singleLine`. In other words

```
 test[0] = singleLine;
```

does not "copy" the content of `singleLine` into `test[0]`, rather it makes `test[0]` to point to the `singleLine`. It has no association with the stored value in `singleLine` at that point of time.

While trying to print the content of the memory location pointed to by `test[0]`, it will always refer to the latest value stored in `singleLine`.

Now, in your while loop, the value of `singleLine` keeps getting updated, and later when you try to print the value after the loop, it prints the last read value which is stored into `singleLine`.

That said,

1. Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)
2. You need to allocate memory to each element of `test` array, and then copy ([`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html)) the content, if you want the values to persist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <string> v;
    string line;    
    ifstream fin("arq.txt");
    while(getline(fin,line)){
        v.push_back(line);
    }
    cout<<v.size();
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/12149471)